# Как добавить Interface в пакет?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, интерфейс

Установил новую версию IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition 2017.3.4x64).
В предыдущей версии IntelliJ все было просто и понятно: <kbd>New</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Class</kbd> ⇒ имя класса ⇒ <kbd>Interface</kbd>.

А теперь что-то поменялось.

Открывается  <kbd>New</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>File</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>Enter a file name</kbd> ⇒ Ввожу имя файла – нет возможности выбрать опцию Interface.

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой и не знаю что делать.

Существует ли возможность еще как-то добавлять Interface в пакет, а не только на пакете <kbd>Правая клавиша</kbd> ⇒ <kbd>New</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

**New** **⇒** **Java Class** **⇒** Вводим имя и выбираем тип класса. Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: New ⇒ Java Class]

Версия: **2020.1.1**

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>New</kbd> → <kbd>Java Class</kbd> → <kbd>Name</kbd> и <kbd>Kind (Class, Interface, Enum...)</kbd>